# How do I make a form box and button disappear upon clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm coding a form on HTML with JS that asks for the user to enter their name and displays it. I would like the form and the button to disappear when they hit submit.

```
<form>
    <br/>What is your name: <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" value="done" onclick="write_name();" />
</form>
<h4 id=welcome></h4>
```

The script is below:

```
function write_name() {
    var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('welcome');
    var name = document.getElementById('name');

    welcome_parra.innerHTML = "Welcome " + name.value + "!";
}
```

Comment: just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
 Jquery Code 

$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn_sbumit").click(function () {
            $(this).next().text($("#name").val());
            $("#name").hide();
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="" />
<input type="button" id="btn_sbumit" value="Submit" />
<span></span>
```

Comment: Must include JQuery library